What does it mean for a data subject to have information?
Article 14 of the GDPR covers information to be provided where personal data has not been obtained from the data subject.  It requires the data subject to be provided with details when a data controller receives personal information from a source other than the data subject themselves.  The requirements are waived on four conditions.  (b) is if it is too hard, (c) is if it is a legal thing and (d) is if it is a secret.  Presumably the main reason every data transfer in this information marketplace we live in does not trigger such a communication is (a) the data subject already has the information;
What exactly does this mean?  Some things that spring to mind that are unclear:

Does someone who does not have the mental capacity to know their address, or even their name, "have" that information?
Does an individual "have" information they had in the past but has since lost/forgotten, such as who they had an insurance policy with a year or two ago, or the exact value of a judgement in the past?
Does an individual "have" their web site activity, which may be monitored to a greater degree than they are consciously aware of themselves?
Do you "have" your IP address if you never look, or do not know how to look, or are using a device which does not allow you to look?

Edit in response to answer
It seems I may have been wrong about what data the data subject must have, but the question remains, what does it mean to "have" the information. Does being emailed a link to a web site with the data count? What if I have deleted the email? Does it being on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard‘?

Once you have been provided with something how is the provider supposed to police your knowledge of, or access to, the thing that was provided?  i.e. why might you not "have" something simply because you chose to "display it on the bottom of a locked filing cabinet..."?

@MichaelHall I am not sure that is relevant.  Is not the question unless the data provider can be certain that the individual actually has the information then they should inform them of the data transfer to avoid the risk of illegality.  It seem like it is really easy if the information exists on the web anyway.  Note it would be the data controller who chose to put it on the bottom of a locked filing cabinet not the data subject.

My question is as relevant as your last edit.  Because you are looking for a definition of "have", and provided that as an example to illustrate your confusion on the matter... But  your clarification in the last sentence is useful.  Seems as if "provided" might be a better term than "have".

@MichaelHall "have" is the term in law.  If the law said "the data subject already has been provided with the information" that would be a different law.

Right, and I merely suggested that if the existing law said "provided" then we wouldn't have questions like this...  (no need for a different law)

P.S. The term "Shall Provide" appears several times... That said, I believe that asking what legal standard a data controller must meet to ensure that information is provided to the subject would be a better question than asking for a legal definition of the word "have" as it pertains to an individual's ability to conveniently access that information. (if indeed that is what you are wanting to know...) I think it's this weird angle to asking about the issue that is garnering the downvotes.

The question asks about an exception to the obligation to provide information under Article 14.


Paragraphs 1 to 4 shall not apply where and insofar as:

(a) the data subject already has the information; ...

This is for circumstances when the data controller claims they already provided the information or another entity provided the information.
The question asks what it means "to have" the information - i.e. what satisfies 14.5(a) - GDPR does not define it. In a dispute about Article 14.5(a), it is for the controller to provide evidence they (at minimum) did what is required.
As a general rule, exceptions should be interpreted and applied narrowly.
It's not sufficient for the data controller to simply assume the data subject has the information. The data controller must be proactive about it. The data controller must document and be able to demonstrate what the information was and how it was provided (the principle of accountability at Article 5.2). It might be less risky to provide the information again on subsequent contacts.
This doesn't necessarily entail personal visits, reading the material to the data subject, clamping their eyes open for a presentation deck. Articles 14 and 13 should be read in conjunction with Article 12.1 (my emphasis):

The controller shall take appropriate measures to provide any information referred to in Articles 13 and 14 and any communication under Articles 15 to 22 and 34 relating to processing to the data subject in a concise, transparent, intelligible and easily accessible form, using clear and plain language, in particular for any information addressed specifically to a child. The information shall be provided in writing, or by other means, including, where appropriate, by electronic means. When requested by the data subject, the information may be provided orally, provided that the identity of the data subject is proven by other means.

This is all part of 'transparency', a guiding principle throughout GDPR.

5.1(a) [Personal data shall be] processed lawfully, fairly and in a transparent manner in relation to the data subject (‘lawfulness, fairness and transparency’);

Recital 39 (not law but used for guidance):

.. The principle of transparency requires that any information and communication relating to the processing of those personal data be easily accessible and easy to understand, and that clear and plain language be used. ... Natural persons should be made aware of risks, rules, safeguards and rights in relation to the processing of personal data and how to exercise their rights in relation to such processing. ...

Transparency isn't precisely defined by GDPR either, but the European Data Protection Board endorsed the Guidelines on transparency under Regulation 2016/679 adopted by the Article 29 Working Party and these are referred to by the regulators and courts.
In the guidelines there is a "best practice example concerning the limited manner in which the Article 13.4 exception should be construed" that can also be used to illustrate the above points.

An individual signs up to an online email service and receives all of the required Article 13.1 and 13.2 information at the point of sign-up.
Six months later the data subject activates a connected instant message functionality through the email service provider and provides their mobile telephone number to do so.
The service provider gives the data subject certain Article 13.1 and 13.2 information about the processing of the telephone number (e.g. purposes and legal basis for processing, recipients, retention period) but does not provide other information that the individual already has from 6 months ago and which has not since changed (e.g. the identity and contact details of the controller and the data protection officer, information on data subject rights and the right to complain to the relevant supervisory authority).
As a matter of best practice however, the complete suite of information should be provided to the data subject again but the data subject also should be able to easily tell what information amongst it is new. The new processing for the purposes of the instant messaging service may affect the data subject in a way which would prompt them to seek to exercise a right they may have forgotten about, having been informed six months prior.
Providing all the information again helps to ensure the data subject
remains well informed about how their data is being used and their rights.


You misunderstand the information that needs to be provided to the data subject
It isn’t the personal data the controller has on the subject, it’s the information about the controller in paragraph (1) that needs to be provided unless the subject already has it or one of the other exemptions applies.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
